# How do I select the subclasses of X and Y safety capacitors?

Tags: power-supply, power, capacitor, safety

While designing a switch-mode power supply, I've been reading a lot about X and Y rated safety capacitor. Although I fully understand their use and limitations, how do I determine if I need a X1 or X2 capacitor across the line and a Y1 or Y2 between line and ground?

I understand that slapping a X1/Y1 everywhere would be easy, but I can't seem to find the standard associated with the appropriate sub-class selection. For cost sensitive products, a X2/Y2 could make a difference. How do I determine if the intended application is within the sub-class' limits?

So far, the only specification I found is the IEC 60384, which specify how these capacitors should be tested, but nothing regarding the appropriate safety rating for a known application.